# Why is my FS.collection failing to insert images, and NOT showing any error messages?

Tags: meteor, collections, insert, client-server, publish-subscribe

After I click the upload an image button on my app, this (event) code is triggered:

/myApp 
../client/main.js

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';
Meteor.subscribe('Images');

FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
var teste = Images.insert(file,  function (err, fileObj) {

var insertedIdSession = teste._id;

    console.log("Total number of images in Images Collection is: " + Images.find().count());
    console.log("Inserted _ID is: " + insertedIdSession);
    console.log("Latest image is:" + Images.find(insertedIdSession));
  },

function( error, result) { 
if ( error ) console.log ( error ); //info about what went wrong
if ( result ) console.log ( result ); //the _id of new object if successful
});
```

The below is the result (image) in the browser console:
[image: The response in the browser console]

The image indicates that no image was **inserted** at all. To confirm this, I also run: `Images.find().fetch()` in the browser which confirmed that nothing was inserted. 
 Further, what is strange is that the error handlers don't show any indication of any error nor result.  ....Wait it gets even stranger, the link at the bottom of the image actually successfully points to the uploaded image. I cant figure out where I am going wrong. Kindly help me out here.

Following are my settings:

/myApp 
../imports/api/tasks.js

```
import { Mongo } from "meteor/mongo";

Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})] });
```

/myApp 
../server/main.js

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {

Meteor.publish('Images', function(){
return Images.find();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your success function

```
var teste = Images.insert(file,  function (err, fileObj) {
```

Takes an "err" parameter, but your code doesn't check it. Maybe that has a clue as to the outcome

Comment: Thanks for the response. I based my coding on the FS.Collection2 library found @ [ https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS ]. B.T.W. the code worked perfectly before I removed autopublish with `meteor remove autopublish`. Does this detail give you a clue?

Comment: Ok, that's an important factlet :) A major aid when trouble shooting after breaking it, is to ask "what has changed?" So it means that something with your publication strategy is broken - maybe you are not allowing insert from the client?

Comment: I am not sure what I altered in the code (Sorry), but it think it was  giving the publishing function the name "publishImages", it now looks like this: `Meteor.publish('Images', function publishImages(){
    return Images.find();
});` Anyway the `Images.insert` function now works, Now just have issues displaying the inserted images in the gallery.

Comment: Git should be your friend during development. Use it to track what has changed. It can be painful to use, but the payback means you won't want to work without it

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Am not sure If these changes made a difference, but by giving the publishing function a name, it now inserts the images. The publishing code now looks like this: `Meteor.publish('Images', function publishImages(){
    return Images.find();
});`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this subtle change in code made the desired result (meaning insert images now work correctly), all I did was give the Meteor publish function a name. From the publishing code previously looking like this (without a name):

```
Meteor.publish('Images', function (){
 return Images.find();
});
```

To the publishing code currently looking like this

```
Meteor.publish('Images', function publishImages (){
return Images.find();
});
```

Thanks guys